# Substring (variable length) values in entire column of dataframe

Tags: r, string, string-matching

I have looked for this tirelessly with no luck. I am coming from a Java background and new to R. (On a side note, I am loving R, but disliking string operations in it as well as the documentation - maybe that's just a Java bias.)

Anyhow, I have a dataframe with a single column, it is composed of a latitude and longitude numbers seperated by a colon e.g. **ROAD:_:-87.4968190989999:38.7414455360001**

I would like to create 2 new data frames where each will have the separate lat and long numbers.

I have successfully written a piece of code where I use for loops (but I know this is inefficient - and that there has to be another way)

Here is a snippet of the inefficient code:

```
length <- length(fromLatLong)

for (i in 1:length){
      fromLat[i] <- strsplit(fromLatLong[i] ,":")[[1]][4]

    }

    for (i in 1:length){
      fromLong[i] <- strsplit(fromLatLong[i] ,":")[[1]][3]

    }

    for (i in 1:length){
      toLat[i] <- strsplit(toLatLong[i] ,":")[[1]][4]

    }

    for (i in 1:length){
      toLong[i] <- strsplit(toLatLong[i] ,":")[[1]][3]

    }
```

Here is how I tried to optimize it using mutate, but I only get the first value copied over to all rows as such:

```
fromLat = mutate(fromLatLong, FROM_NODE_ID = (strsplit(as.character(fromLatLong$FROM_NODE_ID),":")[[1]][4]))
fromLong = mutate(fromLatLong, FROM_NODE_ID = (strsplit(fromLatLong$FROM_NODE_ID,":")[[1]][3]))
toLat = mutate(toLatLong, TO_NODE_ID = (strsplit(toLatLong$TO_NODE_ID,":")[[1]][4]))
toLong = mutate(toLatLong, TO_NODE_ID = (strsplit(toLatLong$TO_NODE_ID,":")[[1]][3]))
```

And here is the result:

```
FROM_NODE_ID

    1
38.7414455360001
2
38.7414455360001
3
38.7414455360001
4
38.7414455360001
5
38.7414455360001
6
38.7414455360001
7
38.7414455360001
8
38.7414455360001
9
38.7414455360001
```

I would appriciete your help on this. Thanks

Comment: Something like `separate` from package *tidyr* might be useful here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `map_chr` function of the `purrr` package. For instance:

```
fromLat = mutate(fromLatLong, FROM_NODE_ID = map_chr(FROM_NODE_ID, ~ strsplit(as.character(.x),":")[[1]][4]))
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. But could you briefly explain? What "~" means and does? And where the ".x" came from and how that reference is understood? I also looked at the map() documentation and didn't understand how this was actually able to solve the problem.

Comment: This approach works because `map_chr` take as input a list or a vector and returns a vector of characters. The formula ("~") is a shorthand to create anonymous function and ".x" is the independent variable. For instance when you use `~ .x + 1` in `map` this is equivalento to `function(x) x + 1`.

The issue with your solution is that `strsplit(as.character(fromLatLong$FROM_NODE_ID),":")` creates a list of splitted strings. In your case you are selecting every time the fourth element of the vector (`[4]`) that is contained in the first element of the list (`[[1]]`).

Answer (score 0):

The following expression will produce a data frame with each of the colon-delimited components as a separate column.  You can then break this up into separate data frames or do whatever else you want with it.

```
as.data.frame(t(matrix(unlist(strsplit(fromLatLong$coords, ":", fixed=TRUE), recursive=FALSE), nrow=4)),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

(Assuming the column name of your values in the data frame is `coords`.)